# Click gmail signout link using Watin

Tags: gmail, watin, internet-explorer-9

I am using IE8 and IE9 on 2 different machines and I want to click the signout link of my gmail account.

Watin is unable to find the signout link and gives me error.

Could anyone please help me and let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks
Yasir

Answer (score 0):

expecting you have created a browser instance I think this will do the trick:

```
var signOutBtn = browser.Frame("canvas_frame").Link(Find.ByText("Sign out"));
signOutBtn.Click();
```

BTW be sure to update to WatiN 2.1 which supports frames in IE9 properly.